# iptables not working on DDWRT firewall

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, iptables

I have write a firewall rules for DDWRT router but I didn't work. What I needed is, I would like to set all my wireless user, once it reach daily quota which is 200mb it will disconnected from the service or throttle the internet speed.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m quota --quota 2048 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m quota --quota 2048 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Comment: What does it do? Is the limit ignored?  I believe 2048 is k so it is now 2mb.

Comment: Ya just 2048 is for testing. The actual amount is 2GB

Comment: 1.  Does it limit traffic at all?  2.  Does it cut off traffic before the expected limit?

Comment: How many NICs do you have and what do they connect to?

Comment: So far you have told the computer to cut off traffic on ALL network cards after the quota has been reached.  If you have eth0 and eth1, for example you need to separate the 2 nics from the INPUT queue or both NICs willbe affected.